# Closing showWaitScreenWithNoClose in SharePoint CSOM

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-clientobject

I am creating a list using REST APIs. In my JavaScript code I have written something like this:

```
// If I declare 'waitDialog' then it is not get closed by 
// calling 'waitDialog.close()'. Without any declaration it works.
var waitDialog;

function createList() {

    // Show wait dialog
    waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Please wait...", "Please wait...", 100, 300);

    jQuery.ajax({
        // List data
        },
        success: doSuccess,
        error: doError
    });
}

function doSuccess(data) {
    waitDialog.close(); // Close wait dialog
}

function doError(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    waitDialog.close(); // Close wait dialog
}
```

If I declare `waitDialog` with statement `var waitDialog;` then it does *not* work by calling `waitDialog.close()`. Without any declaration it works and the dialog is closed. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1047998) which elaborates on the difference between using `var`, but nothing which would clarify this case.

Any idea why does it work without declaration and not with declaration?

Answer (score 3):

I could not recreate your declaration issue.
One thing I noticed... I believe you need to pass the SP.UI.DialogResult enumerable to the close method

```
waitDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

//show and hide waiting on it javascript

```
function waitMessage() {
    window.parent.eval("window.waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', '', 90, 300);");
}

function closeMessage() {
    if (window.frameElement != null) {
        if (window.parent.waitDialog != null) {
            window.parent.waitDialog.close();
        }
    }
}
```